# In android WebView Error handling not working

Tags: android, android-webview

When requested invalid URL, Controller never coming to "onReceivedError" method. But while loading valid page "onProgressChanged" is called properly.

Code:

```
try {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewEvents);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                System.out.println("on Progress Changes : ");
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                System.out.println("on Error received : ");
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while loading: " + e);
    }
```